# In MySQL Master to Master replication, If I change MySQL root login password on one MySQL server will that automatically change on other MySQL Server?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have Master to Master replication. If I change MySQL 'root' login password on one Server,will that affect another Server ?

Comment: One master needs to be able to login to the other master, and part of the replication configuration is an appropriate username and password, which both need to be correct for the other master.

Comment: I have Master to Master replication. If I change MySQL 'root' login password on one Server,will that replicated on other MySQL server and change root login password

Answer (score 0):

Passwords are stored in your database, schema mysql, table user. So it will be replicated, unless you specified to ignore this schema/table from replication with `replicate-ignore-db` or `replicate-ignore-table` or `binlog-ignore-db` or `binlog-ignore-table`.

You can read more about these variables [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-slave.html).

Comment: I think small confusion. I am asking about root user of mysql login. Will it be same rule?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about exactly that. No need to downvote. All mysql user logins are stored in mysql.user. I actually wonder what else could be meant. There are no other type of users or whatever.

Comment: @UjwalKhairnar Did I clear things up with my last comment? For further clarification you can do a `select user, host from mysql.user;`